# Error while using inspectdb in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I already have an application using PostgreSQL as db. I want to build a service using Django. Tried "inspectdb"... but it is giving an expection:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
   utility.execute()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
   self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
   self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
   output = self.handle(*args, **options)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py", line 25, in handle
   for line in self.handle_inspection(options):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py", line 70, in handle_inspection
   constraints = connection.introspection.get_constraints(cursor, table_name)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/introspection.py", line 172, in get_constraints
   "foreign_key": tuple(used_cols[0].split(".", 1)) if kind.lower() == "foreign key" else None,
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Hm, is it a very large database? Could you manage to just write the models yourself?

Comment: Hi Kris, lots of relations are there. Thought this would be error-prone

Comment: I hear you, but I wouldn't rely on such a shortcut. It's bound to make mistakes anyways - I believe you encountered one haha. I would code the models myself, and write a database migration script to copy stuff from your database over to django's in decent sized chunks. Its tedious, but I'm not sure how else you could do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out the issue.

Apparently, the db user didn't have sufficient permissions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11188005)

Comment: I think it was the issue. That was the same explanation given at Django forum also: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25476#comment:25